# Can Recursive-Do Be Desugared

Tags: haskell, recursion

Can a recursive-do statement be desugared to a series of `>>=` statements? If so, what does the [reverse state monad's definition for `>>=`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/rev-state-0.1.2/docs/src/Control-Monad-Trans-RevState.html#line-59) look like when it's desugared?

```
instance MonadFix m => Monad (StateT s m) where
  return x = ...
  m >>= f = StateT $ \s -> do
    rec
      (x, s'') <- runStateT m s'
      (x', s') <- runStateT (f x) s
    return (x', s'')
```

Comment: In general, recursive-do can't be desugared _only_ to a series of `>>=` calls, there would also have to be an `mfix` call.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Recursive-do desugars not only to a series of `>>=` calls, but also, as long as there is actually recursion, into an `mfix` call. It is in the `mfix` call that the whole recursiveness happens, via what is technically termed "magic fairy dust".

Seriously though, how it happens is different for every monad, and that's why it's a class `MonadFix` rather than just a function. But the important point is that it can "magically" pass you your own result as a parameter, which is only possible due to Haskell's laziness, and therefore must be handled with care.

In general, something like this:

```
do
    rec 
        x <- f y
        y <- g x
    return $ h x y
```

Desugars into this:

```
mfix (\ ~(x, y) -> do
    x' <- f y
    y' <- g x'
    return (x', y')
)
>>= (\(x, y) -> h x y)
```

So applying to the reverse state definition, it would look like this:

```
m >>= f = StateT $ \s ->
  mfix (\ ~((x, s''), (x',s')) -> do
    (x0, s0'') <- runStateT m s'
    (x0', s0') <- runStateT (f x0) s
    return ((x0, s0''), (x0', x0'))
  )
  >>= (\(x, s''), (x',s') -> return (x', s''))
```

And from here, we can just desugar the regular `do` as usual:

```
m >>= f = StateT $ \s ->
  mfix (\ ~((x, s''), (x',s')) ->
    runStateT m s' >>= \(x0, s0'') ->
    runStateT (f x0) s >>= \(x0', s0') ->
    return ((x0, s0''), (x0', x0'))
  )
  >>= (\(x, s''), (x',s') -> return (x', s''))
```

(that is, unless I messed up something - a lot of ticks flying around :-)

Comment: A couple of things: your last code block has an extraneous ```do```, and the variable ```s``` is out of scope.

Comment: Thanks! I think I got a handle on it. I ended up simplifying with ```m >>= f = StateT $ \s -> mfix (\ ~(s', (x, _)) -> runStateT m s' >>= \(x, s0'') -> runStateT (f x) s >>= \(x', s0') -> return (s0', (x', s0'')) ) >>= (\(_, r) -> return r)```